# HTTPS rewrite by htaccss

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the php rewrite code on my website htaccess file for https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Here is my issue**

my website redirect 
http://www.example.org  --301--> https://www.example.org --301--> https://example.org

Since the first one (http://www.example.org) has 400+ backlinks it would be best to redirect straight to the https://example.org and avoid that middle step.

**can someone tell me the proper re-write code?**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: with the new code i get https://%7Bhttp_host%7D/ with a http:// request

Comment: So when you make a request to http://www.example.org you get redirected to https://%7Bhttp_host%7D/ ? Sorry I do not understand the problem

Comment: yes, that is correct. not sure why that is happening